Input Field value passed by using selenium disappears
An input field deletes the value after it's entered using SendKeys via JS in Selenium. The value appears briefly, then disappears. How to fix this?
I am using Java with selenium & maven.
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(DriverManager.getDriver(), Duration.ofSeconds(10));
 WebElement field = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("spocData[0].spocDetails.email")));
 
 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) DriverManager.getDriver();
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", field);
 js.executeScript("arguments[0].value='test346@gmail.com';", field);

I have tried multiple xpath.
Selenium Sendkeys method.
Sendkeys by Mouse Actions.
Tried Resetup of whole project.

Without seeing the page, my guess is that the page isn't fully loaded when you enter text into the fields then once the page is completely loaded, the fields are reset. Also, setting values on fields using JS is generally not a good idea for just this reason. Use .sendKeys() and see if that fixes the problem. No user is going to use JS to set values so you are shortcutting around potential page functionality. Type into the field like a user would and that might solve the issue.

I have used .sendkeys(), sendkeys with Mouse Actions and then still this isn't working thats why using JavaScript. Also the page is fully loaded as I can operate on other elements of the page  Also the . sendkeys() method is only not working on my laptop, my colleagues are able to run test case successfully with same code.

Share the URL with us.

As JeffC has mentioned in the comments it is very hard to determine without seeing the page/URL.
I would suggest to try the following:
//Wait until the page is fully loaded
WebDriver driver      = DriverManager.getDriver();
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
WebDriverWait wait    = new WebDriverWait(driver, Duration.ofSeconds(10));
wait.until(driver -> {return js.executeScript("return document.readyState").equals("complete");});

WebElement field = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.elementToBeClickable(By.id("spocData[0].spocDetails.email")));

// scroll the field into view and focus on it

js.executeScript("arguments[0].scrollIntoView(true);", field);
js.executeScript("arguments[0].focus();", field);

// implement a simple retry mechanism
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
field.sendKeys("test346@gmail.com");
if (field.getAttribute("value").equals("test346@gmail.com")) {
    break;
 }
}

Hope this helps

The problem is same code works on the Colleague's laptop. I have done the clean project setup again & also installed clean java, maven, everything. Still the same, not able to find out what is the root cause.
